# Condicional IF en PHP

Tags: php, html

Sé que como tal, en HTML no se puede usar la condicional if, pero con PHP se puede integrar perfectamente.

Lo que busco es que en vez de hacer el condicional completamente en PHP:

```
<?php
if (condicion) {
   echo "<p>hola</p>";
} else {
   echo "<p>adios</p>";
}
?>
```

Implementar mejor PHP y que el HTML no tenga que llevar `echo` por cada elemento.

```
<?php if (condition): ?>
    <p>Hola</p>;
<?php else if (condition): ?>   
    <p>Adios</p>;
<?php endif; ?>
```

Por lo que veo la parte del código `<?php else if (condition): ?>` no existe, o no se escribe así, pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo, ¿o tengo que hacer cada condicional por separado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Del [manual](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.elseif.php) de *PHP*:

> Nota: Tenga en cuenta que elseif y else if serán considerados exactamente iguales sólamente cuando se utilizan llaves como en el ejemplo anterior. **Al utilizar los dos puntos para definir las condiciones if/elseif, no debe separarse else if en dos palabras** o PHP fallará con un error del interprete.

Quiere dedir que la forma correcta de hacerlo sería `else if` junto:

```
<?php if (condition): ?>
    <p>Hola</p>;
<?php elseif (condition): ?>   
    <p>Adios</p>;
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Justo lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 2):

Otra cosa que podrias hacer es asignar el valor de lo que quieres mostrar en una variable, luego muestras un solo echo:

```
<?php
if (condition) {
   $resultado = "hola";
} elseif(condition) {
   $resultado = "adios";
}

echo "<p>".$resultado."</p>";
?>
```